# Python asyncio queue not updated

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio

The following code instantiates an `asyncio.Queue` object, and tries to populate and consume this queue from two different coroutines, respectively `arrival()` and `server()`.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
q = asyncio.Queue()

async def arrival(q):
    print('ARRIVAL - Queue id:', id(q))

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        item = random.choice(['item1', 'item2'..., 'item100'])
        q.put(item)

        print('ARRIVAL - added {}, qsize is now {}'.format(item, q.qsize()))


async def server(q):
    print('SERVER - Queue id:', id(q))

    while True:
        item = await q.get()
        print('SERVER - taking {}, qsize is now {}'.format(item, q.qsize()))

        await asyncio.sleep(1.8)
        print('SERVER - finished processing {}'.format(item))


tasks = [loop.create_task(arrival(q)), loop.create_task(server(q))]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

The principle is the following:

- Every 1 second, an item is added to `q`
- Anytime the server is free, it takes the next item in the queue or waits for it
- The server takes 1.8 seconds to process an item

The expected output would be:

```
SERVER - Queue id: 12345678
ARRIVAL - Queue id: 12345678
ARRIVAL - added item1, qsize is now 1
SERVER - taking item1, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item2, qsize is now 1
SERVER - finished processing item1
SERVER - taking item2, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item3, qsize is now 1
ARRIVAL - added item4, qsize is now 2
SERVER - finished processing item2
SERVER - taking item3, qsize is now 1
ARRIVAL - added item5, qsize is now 2
ARRIVAL - added item6, qsize is now 3
SERVER - finished processing item3
SERVER - taking item4, qsize is now 2
```

However when I run the above code, the elements in `while True` loop in `server()` are never executed, `q.qsize()` is always 0, and the output is:

```
SERVER - Queue id: 12345678
ARRIVAL - Queue id: 12345678
ARRIVAL - added item1, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item2, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item3, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item4, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item5, qsize is now 0
...
```

It seems that the `q` object is never updated by `arrival()` (`q.qsize()` is always 0) and hence `server()` is never aware of the items added by `arrival()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got this running in the way you want it to:

```
import asyncio
import random

random.seed(31415)  # get reproducible runs

ITEMS = ['item{}'.format(i) for i in range(100)]

async def arrival(q):
    queue_object_id = id(q)
    print('ARRIVAL - Queue id:', queue_object_id)
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        item = random.choice(ITEMS)
        await q.put(item)
        size = q.qsize()
        print('ARRIVAL - added {}, qsize is now {}'.format(item, size))

async def server(q):
    queue_object_id = id(q)
    print('SERVER - Queue id:', queue_object_id)

    while True:
        item = await q.get()
        size = q.qsize()
        print('SERVER - taking {}, qsize is now {}'.format(item, size))
        await asyncio.sleep(1.8)
        print('SERVER - finished processing {}'.format(item))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
q = asyncio.Queue()
cors = asyncio.wait([arrival(q), server(q)])
loop.run_until_complete(cors)
```

unfortunately i did not track all the changes i had to make... sorry. but i'm sure you find out the differences and why they make a difference.

this produces the output:

```
SERVER - Queue id: 140540011741592
ARRIVAL - Queue id: 140540011741592
ARRIVAL - added item75, qsize is now 1
SERVER - taking item75, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item36, qsize is now 1
SERVER - finished processing item75
SERVER - taking item36, qsize is now 0
ARRIVAL - added item57, qsize is now 1
ARRIVAL - added item5, qsize is now 2
SERVER - finished processing item36
SERVER - taking item57, qsize is now 1
ARRIVAL - added item69, qsize is now 2
ARRIVAL - added item67, qsize is now 3
SERVER - finished processing item57
SERVER - taking item5, qsize is now 2
ARRIVAL - added item53, qsize is now 3
ARRIVAL - added item16, qsize is now 4
SERVER - finished processing item5
SERVER - taking item69, qsize is now 3
ARRIVAL - added item91, qsize is now 4
...
```

Comment: Thanks! The meaningful bit was calling `await q.put(item)` instead of just `q.put(item)`. Makes sense since `q.put` is a coroutine, but somehow I missed it.

Comment: @Jivan yes, wanted to add that this was one of the more important things i changed... sorry. & happy new year!

Comment: On the other hand, replacing `asyncio.gather()` with `asyncio.wait()` doesn't seem to have any effect, in this case at least. I should investigate the difference in the docs. Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

**TL&DR**: Make sure to await both the put() and the get() when using asyncio queue.

**Rational**: In both the get() and the put() functions within asyncio queue, they are both co-routines, and therefore will need to be awaited.

**Example**:

```
await q.put(item)
await q.get(item)
```